# What is equivalent to npm install --save in elixir mix with hex

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Is there an equivalent to `npm install --save` for quick adding hex module to mix.exs ?

I know pasting hex module references do `mix.exs` `deps` function like this:

```
defp deps do
    [
        {:asn, "~> 0.2.1"},
        {:mix_docker, "~> 0.3.0"}
    ]
  end
```

shouldn't be a big deal, but I've got accustomed to convention

```
npm install --save xyz
```

and the module is downloaded and installed in `packages.json` configuration file. Very handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such thing. You need to add dependencies manually to your `mix.exs`.